# Zend Date doesn't check leap year

Tags: zend-framework, date, leap-year

I have this code

```
$dateObject = new Zend_Date('2013-02-28', 'yyyy.mm.dd');
$dateObject->addDay(2);
$newDate = $dateObject->toString('yyyy-mm-dd);
```

This gives me $newDate = '2013-02-30'; which is not a valid date for database input. Help guys.

Comment: which zend version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have given invalid format. Try this,

```
$dateObject = new Zend_Date('2013-02-28');
$dateObject->addDay(2);
$newDate = $dateObject->toString('Y-MM-dd'); // 2013-03-02
```